# My Image is not rendering in reactjs typescript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating an app using **reactjs **and **typescript **however I encountered an issue while loading **images **inside a component.

## My error in console

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../images/test.png'
    at webpackEmptyContext...
```

## This is my component:

```
import { IProject } from '../interfaces/IProject'
import pin from '../svgs/pin.svg'

function Project(props: { project: IProject }) {
  const project = props.project

  return (
    <>
      <div className='project'>
        <img className='pin' src={pin} alt='pin' />
        <div>
          <img alt='project gif' src={require(project.image)} />
          <span>{project.title}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Project
```

**NB :** The images are stored inside a 'images' folder and the project component is stored inside a 'components' folder
**NB#2 : **the first image 'pin' loads normally.

*Thank you for all the help ~ sorry if this a nooby question.*

## I tried

- replacing `(project.image)` with `('../images/test.png')` and it works if I do that but I want to be able to display the image src passed by the props.
- for testing purposes, I added a `const projectImage = '../images/test.png` and replacing `require(project.image)` with `require(projectImage)` and it doesn't work
- I created **index.d.ts** file (according to solutions I found on the internet) and added `declare module '*.jpg'` and the same thing for jpeg and png. It didn't fix my issue
- changing the path of the image
- I also installed **file-loader**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update variable value to contain only the name like this

```
 project.image = 'test.png'
```

then add the relative path

```
require(`../images/${project.image}`)
```